# How to check which foreign key yelds the results

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys

Let's suppose I have a database with 4 tables, for cataloguing books. For every book I want to store the title, one or more authors, and one or more translators.
The structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `book` (
    `book_id`   INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    `title` TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE `person` (
    `person_id` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    `surname`   TEXT,
    `name`  INTEGER
);
CREATE TABLE `author` (
    `book_id`   INTEGER,
    `person_id` INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(`book_id`) REFERENCES book(book_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(`person_id`) REFERENCES person(person_id)
);
CREATE TABLE `translator` (
    `book_id`   INTEGER,
    `person_id` INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(`book_id`) REFERENCES book(book_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(`person_id`) REFERENCES person(person_id)
);
INSERT into book VALUES(1, 'Divine Comedy');
INSERT into person VALUES(1, 'Alighieri', 'Dante');
INSERT into person VALUES(2, 'Binyon', 'Laurence');
INSERT into author VALUES(1, 1);
INSERT into translator VALUES(1, 2);
```

When I query the database for the title 'Divine Comedy' I have this (somehow expected) results:

```
SELECT book.title, person.surname, person.name FROM book, person WHERE book.title='Divine Comedy';

Divine Comedy|Alighieri|Dante
Divine Comedy|Binyon|Laurence
```

The problem is, how do I know which person is selected as an author and which as a translator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query is not correct; it filters for the book, but then it combines this with *all* persons in the database.

To get only those persons that are somehow related to a book, you have to filter with that relationship:

```
SELECT book.title, person.surname, person.name
FROM book
JOIN author USING (book_id)
JOIN person USING (person_id)
WHERE book.title = 'Divine Comedy';

SELECT book.title, person.surname, person.name
FROM book
JOIN translator USING (book_id)
JOIN person USING (person_id)
WHERE book.title = 'Divine Comedy';
```

If you want to get all results in a single query, just combine both queries:

```
SELECT book.title, person.surname, person.name, 'author' AS type
FROM book
JOIN author USING (book_id)
JOIN person USING (person_id)
WHERE book.title = 'Divine Comedy'
UNION ALL
SELECT book.title, person.surname, person.name, 'translator' AS type
FROM book
JOIN translator USING (book_id)
JOIN person USING (person_id)
WHERE book.title = 'Divine Comedy';
```

Alternatively, combine both relationship tables into a single [common table expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html):

```
WITH relationship(book_id, person_id, type) AS (
  SELECT book_id, person_id, 'author'     FROM author
  UNION ALL
  SELECT book_id, person_id, 'translator' FROM translator
)
SELECT book.title, person.surname, person.name, relationship.type
FROM book
JOIN relationship USING (book_id)
JOIN person USING (person_id)
WHERE book.title = 'Divine Comedy';
```

Comment: I suppose I completely missed the point of foreign keys, which as far as I now understand is to ensure referential integrity and has nothing to do with querying data. Am I right?

Comment: Yes; they are actually called "foreign key *constraints*".